# Why does mypy not accept a list[str] as a list[Optional[str]]?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

Example 1:

```
from typing import List, Optional

def myfunc() -> List[Optional[str]]:
    some_list = [x for x in "abc"]
    return some_list
```

[Mypy complains](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=3c3815740d4a2e013a4b4a572d9ac40f) on example 1:

> Incompatible return value type (got "List[str]", expected
> "List[Optional[str]]")

However, this example [gets no complaint](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&flags=show-error-codes%2Cstrict&gist=b5c217866a358e5dd619822668a37f21):

Example 2:

```
def myfunc() -> List[Optional[str]]:
    some_list = [x for x in "abc"]
    return list(some_list)
```

What is the explanation for the inconsistent behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since in Python lists are invariant (see the examples [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#variance) and [here](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#variance-of-generic-types)).

If we pass `List[str]` to someone that expects `List[Optional[str]]`, that someone may add a `None` to our list and break our assumptions. The second example is valid however as the output of `list()` in the return statement is not saved anywhere and no one can depend on the the returned value being mutated illegally .

Comment: list invariance is sure part of the story, but i'd also expect python to be able to infer the types here regardless. I consider it a bug that mypy's too eager in inferring the type of `some_list` as `list[str]`

Comment: @joel I'd consider that a feature request, and it's not obvious what the behaviour should be. There would be similar examples to this code where you want `List[str]` for the intermediate variable.

Comment: @kaya3 yes you're right it is a feature request. I went as far as calling it a bug because I feel it's so important to user experience