# Subclass overriding attribute with subtype of parent's attribute

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

```py
class B:
    pass


class InheritsB1(B):
    pass


class InheritsB2(B):
    pass


class A:
    prop: list[B]


class InheritsA1(A):
    prop: list[InheritsB1]


class InheritsA2(A):
    prop: list[InheritsB2]
```

With this code mypy raises `Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "List[InheritsB2]", base class "A" defined the type as "List[B]")`.

How can I make this work?

`InheritsB1` is a subclass of `B`, so `list[InheritsB1]` is always a list of `B`. How can I tell mypy that it's not incompatible? Or, how can I tell mypy that the `prop` in `A` is "list of `B` or any specific subclass of `B`"?

I understand the issue here: [mypy trouble with inheritance of objects in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305636/mypy-trouble-with-inheritance-of-objects-in-lists). But in this case I want the `prop` object to be a list of a specific instances (`B` or any subclass of `B`). I know it will never be mixed, as in it will always be `list[B]` or `list[SubclassOfB1]` or `list[SubclassOfB2]`, never `list[SubclassOfB1 | SubclassOfB2]`. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does mypy not accept a list\[str\] as a list\[Optional\[str\]\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479559/why-does-mypy-not-accept-a-liststr-as-a-listoptionalstr)

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53275080/mypy-creating-a-type-that-accepts-list-of-instances-of-subclasses

Comment: No, those questions don't really explain how to fix the issue of List not being valid, which the answer to this question does. The solution was to create classes with a generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked a post that essentially addresses the issue, but you seem to still be confused:

> `InheritsB1` is a subclass of `B`, so `list[InheritsB1]` is always a list of `B`.

This is not true. To quote from [this section](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#covariance-and-contravariance) of PEP 484:

> By default generic types are considered *invariant* in all type variables

The theory [section on variance](https://peps.python.org/pep-0483/#covariance-and-contravariance) in PEP 483 attempts to explain the concepts in much greater detail. I suggest you read through PEP 483 as well as PEP 484, if you want to get more serious about type safety.

The `mypy` complaint is justified and unless you want to follow the tip provided by `mypy` and change the type to something covariant like `Sequence` instead, you will have to work a bit more with generics yourself.

---

How best to solve *your* particular conundrum depends on other factors around your classes that are still ambiguous in your original post.

But one option might be to make `A` [**generic**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#user-defined-generic-types) in terms of a type variable that has an upper bound of `B`. Then, if you want to define a subclass of `A` to hold elements of a *specific* subtype of `B`, there would be no problem:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


_BType = TypeVar("_BType", bound="B")


class B:
    pass


class SubB(B):
    pass


class A(Generic[_BType]):
    attribute: list[_BType]


class SubA(A[SubB]):
    # attribute: list[SubB]
    ...


reveal_type(SubA().attribute)  # Revealed type is "builtins.list[SubB]"
```

Note that in this setup, you don't even have to override/annotate `SubA.attribute` (which is why I commented it out) because you specify the type argument for `A` to be `SubB` during inheritance, which means that `SubA` is no longer generic and `attribute` will always be inferred as `list[SubB]`.

The code is type safe (passes `mypy --strict`), but it still may or may not be practical for you, depending on what other requirements you have for the classes involved. If you provide more details, I can try to amend my answer to better suit your setup.

Comment: This kind of TypeVar declaration was exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Declaring the original attribute as Sequence[B] instead of List[B] also seems to work, but I prefer your solution because it allows me to then call subclasses with the right property subclass at definition time rather than adding hints to every class.